# Partial Upgrade 11.10 to 12.04 stuck

Tags: 11.10, 12.04, upgrade

Help!
Stuck within upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04..
It is now running a partial upgrade and just hangs...
USB access and internet access (via USB wireless) appears to have dropped out,
though I managed to download a sizable amount of update before this - half or more of the upgrades were installed.

Local loopback
RX packets:4 errors: 0

sudo apt-get update

```
failed to fetch...
```

sudo apt-get install -f

```
no longer required are kdesudo libknewstuff2-4 update-manager-kde python-kde4
```

edit: one of the sudo commands I did allowed a fresh upgrade (not partial)... Maybe sudo dpkg -configure -a ??

Or maybe the following from another forum response:

```
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.backup
sudo sed -i -e 's/precise/oneiric/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

The terminal gave me no feedback on those commands, but maybe that  enabled the distribution upgrade from fresh.
It now appears to be fetching files again (very slowly)...

Nope, back to the Wireless disappearing from Ubuntu again, but it's not the wireless, as I'm doing fine on Windows..

Edit: Ah, for some reason it depopulated the SSID field in the Network settings. Simply filled it with the network name. Hopefully all is resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your system didn't like the update. Something installed or some setting is obviously holding it back from completing the update.
The easiest thing to do is create an Ubuntu LiveUSB of 12.04, boot it up, back up your files, and install from scratch. This will save any terminal-hassles.

Comment: No, I managed to do it myself as above, it was a power-off during installation I think...
When prompted to "keep the local version currently installed", obviously I should choose the package version option instead, as the menu.list was only edited in order to restart the process.

Comment: Was surprised by a new message though towards the end of the process though: "tracker-extract closed unexpectedly" and no memory to send info to developers.